# добавление голосовой модели в tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

с помощью RVC я сделал голосовую модель, при попытке добавить её в код получается такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test.py", line 31, in
<module>
    voice_synthesis(text, model_path, config_path)
   File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test.py", line 10, in
voice_synthesis
    model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py",
line 900, in load
    result = load_partial(export_dir, None, tags, options)["root"]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py",
line 1005, in load_partial
    loader_impl.parse_saved_model_with_debug_info(export_dir))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py",
line 59, in parse_saved_model_with_debug_info
    saved_model = parse_saved_model(export_dir)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py",
line 119, in parse_saved_model
    raise IOError( OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: G_2333333.pth\>>>{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

вот сам код:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pyttsx3
import json



def voice_synthesis(text, model_path, config_path):
    model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)

    with open(config_path, 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)

    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.setProperty('rate', config['rate'])
    engine.setProperty('volume', config['volume'])
    engine.setProperty('voice', config['voice'])

    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


model_path = 'G_2333333.pth'
config_path = 'venv/config.json'
text = 'Привет! Как дела?'
voice_synthesis(text, model_path, config_path)
```

уже пробовал перенести "G_2333333" в venv/lib/site-packages но появляется другая ошибка:

```
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in
_find_and_load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line
980, in exec_module   File "<frozen site>", line 616, in <module 
File "<frozen site>", line 599, in main   File "<frozen site>", line
531, in venv   File "<frozen site>", line 384, in addsitepackages  
File "<frozen site>", line 226, in addsitedir   File "<frozen site>",
line 179, in addpackage   File
"C:\Users\kostr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1251.py",
line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position
1992: character maps to <undefined>
```

подскажите, возможно ли это вообще как-то реализовать, если да, то как

Comment: Переустановите tensorflow. Похоже на то, что какой-то из его файлов при установке был поврежден.